# USB attached SATA - partitions table not being read at boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb

Linux apparently fails to identify partitions in a USB-attached SATA disk, if the system is booted with said disk plugged in. This causes partitions (and therefore filesystems) to be invisible, requiring either a partition rescan (partprobe, blockdev --rereadpt, etc), a UAS module re-load, or to unplug the drive & re-plug it back in. None of those are feasible if the disk in question is intended to be the boot device, with ESP and root filesystem in it.

Some experiments were done. Results:

1. Plugging in disk with host online and UAS module loaded -> **works**
2. Plugging in disk with host online and UAS & usb_storage modules NOT loaded -> **works**
3. With disk plugged in, booting the system from an another drive -> **fails**
   Partitions not detected. After giving it plenty of time to settle, the following is observed: Both UAS and usb_storage modules loaded; /dev/sda and /sys/class/block/sda exist; Interestingly lsblk does *not* list it, neither does /proc/partitions.

   1. From this state, unloading and re-loading UAS module -> **works** (lsblk lists it, /dev/sda{1,2} are created, everything "normal")
   2. Also from this state, rescanning partition via blockdev --rereadpt -> **works**
   3. Repeating test with and without UAS module pre-loaded via kernel command line yields same result.
4. With disk plugged in, attempt to boot the system from same disk -> **fails** (system does not boot. Dropped to rescue shell.)

   1. Once dropped to the shell, attempting to `blockdev --rereadpt` -> **works**
   2. Repeating test with and without UAS module pre-loaded via kernel command line yields same result.

Output of `dmesg | grep sd` executed from test case #3 (at 42 seconds a blockdev --rereadpt was executed). Output of same from case #4 is identical.

```
[   13.831953] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   13.831955] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[   13.831956] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[   13.832435] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[   13.832850] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Asking for cache data failed
[   13.832853] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   15.038494] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   15.038497] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[   15.038498] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[   15.039379] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   42.833001] sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[   42.834148] sda: detected capacity change from 0 to 1000204886016
[   42.956764]  sda: sda1 sda2
```

Any hints? I assume the device takes a bit to spin-up and become ready (from the `Logical unit is in process of becoming ready` messages), and maybe the partition scan happens while the device is not ready, failing or getting invalid data. I do not know when this scan happens, or which subsystem causes it. Does it have to do anything with udev? Any other possible culprits? At first I thought that, perhaps, the on-demand module loading caused it to be unavailable when it was needed. So I tried to force it to be loaded - apparently something that can be accomplished by listing the module's name on the kernel command line - but to no avail.

`rootwait` and `rootdelay` have been tested. Both fail to address the problem.

I find it interesting to remark that a run-of-the-mill USB memory stick *works* for the intended purpose of booting off of it (ESP and root filesystem). Also, USB-attached SATA disk is detected by BIOS, UEFI executable (GRUB) found & launched, GRUB read and booted kernel from it, etc.

--

Question's background:

I have a USB to SATA cable I'm using to connect a 2,5in HDD to a machine. The machine is a little home server with 4 internal SATA ports, all in use for RAIDZ member disks. I intend to boot off the external drive, and have root filesystem in there. Up until this point, I had ESP and root filesystem in a 8GB USB stick and it works great... until it doesn't. I've found that a USB stick will *very* quickly shit its pants if put through the workload a typical root filesystem endures, even if journald logs are redirected to RAM and everything but essential processes are run in LXC containers, which have their root filesystems in the ZFS pool.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your adapter. Are you using an enclosure or one of those "bare" adapters?

Comment: Please **don't** examine `dmesg` with `grep` - that's ok to quickly look is something is there, but always look at the complete output with context. You are throwing away relevant information like error messages, which makes diagnosis nearly impossible. So please edit your question and provide the full context for the at least three locations in your `dmesg` output.

Comment: @dirkt I went through dmesg line by line, and found nothing of interest (at least to my eye) other than what I posted here. I omitted everything else when posting here to avoid cluttering the question.

Comment: The problem is that what *you* think may not be of interest may very well be. If you could decide what the problem was, you wouldn't need to ask, would you? All one can see from the messages you gave is that the device is not ready. One can't see if there was a previous command sent to that device which is keeping it busy. One can't see the timing of that command. Etc., etc. ... Of course it's entirely possible that the normal messages just don't have enough information to find out what's wrong, then one needs to enable debugging messages in some kernel parts.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging around, I found a hack-ish solution to this problem.  **It is far from perfect, and it does not address the root cause, but it will at least make the system bootable.**

The hack is to have a script in *initramfs* that executes just before trying to mount root, but after device initialization, and `sleep`s a moment before executing `blockdev --rereadpt`.

In a debian-based system, simply put the following file in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/rereadpt`:

```
#!/bin/sh
PREREQ=""

prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
# get pre-requisites
prereqs)
    prereqs 
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

sleep 5
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/<yourdisknode>
```

You can use `/dev/sda`-like names if your site environment has a single SCSI disk, or `/dev/disk/by-id/...`, or whatever other logic to ensure you're triggering the rescan on the correct drive.

UPDATE: If you don't want `update-initramfs` to execute the aforementioned script every time it rebuilds the image (even though it supposedly, shouldn't??), you **must not omit** the `prereqs` and `case` snippet at the beginning